# Can I use any C# library in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

From what I understand Xamarin provides most (if not all) features of C# for mobile app development. Does that mean I can use any C# library (say, nAudio or something else), provided it is compatible with a target platform? And how to see if a library compatible with a mobile platform?

Comment: The best way would be to try it, have you tried it? See the limitations: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/

Comment: @JeremyThompson I can't really _try_ it since I'm just looking into different ways of making a C# desktop app available for mobile devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand it you should learn how .net is **Fragmented**.

[image]

nAudio uses most of the .net framework APIs and Windows Native APIs, so simply u can't use this with Xamarin.

Even if you think Xamarin can targets Windows, you have no corresponding API in the version of .Net subsystem.

Only possible solutions will be moving the code to server, and let it server all the clients.

or

Rewriting the nAudio for Xamarin

Comment: So, basically, when using Xamarin I am limited to libraries that provide easier ways of doing something (like more math calculations, etc) and anything hardware/driver-related is unavailable? That stings.

Comment: @BarsiktheCat, not at all but yes. otherwise you / the library developer must have developed the library by having API switching depending on the platform.